# How to check the signal quality of a cellular network

Tags: windows-phone-7

The challenge is that I need to receive status of network availability and, if it is a very low signal, run some action. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [MSDN How To: Detect Network Changes for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh487166%28v=vs.92%29.aspx#BMK_NETDET_REGISTERING). It could at least point you in the right direction.